# XSLT 1.0 if condition

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

can you help me please?

If there are differents at "PackingslipId"-"LineInformation"-"Lines" i don´t like to have "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" on "HeaderInformation".

If the "PackingslipId" is always the same at "LineInformation"-"Item" than on "HeaderInformation" the output "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" is ok.

Please note: (I don´t no if important; it also can be, that there is just one Article ("LineInformation"-"Item" - with "OrderLineNum" 1) - in this case, the "PackingslipId" is the same of "Item" and "HeaderInformation" so "PackingslipId" and "DeliveryDate" should be also on "HeaderInformation" and "LineItem"

My XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
 <Interchange>
  <Recipient></Recipient>
  <Sender></Sender>
  <CreationDate></CreationDate>
  <Test></Test>
  <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
 </Interchange>
 <HeaderInformation>
  <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
  <InvoiceType>INVOIC</InvoiceType>
  <InvoiceDate>2019.01.23</InvoiceDate>
  <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>
  <PurchOrderReference>fddf</PurchOrderReference>
  <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
  <CustomerOrderReference>fdgfdg</CustomerOrderReference>
  <PackingslipId>1079304</PackingslipId>
  <DeliveryDate>2019.01.23</DeliveryDate>
  <Currency></Currency>
  <WeightAndVolume />
  <DeliveryAddressInformation>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
  </DeliveryAddressInformation>
  <InvoiceAddressInformation>
   <GLN></GLN>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
   <VATNum></VATNum>
   <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
  </InvoiceAddressInformation>
  <BuyerAddressInformation />
  <SupplierAddressInformation>
   <GLN></GLN>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
   <VATNum></VATNum>
   <Contact />
  </SupplierAddressInformation>
 </HeaderInformation>
 <LineInformation>
  <Item>
   <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>
   <GTIN></GTIN>
   <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
   <PackingslipId>1079304</PackingslipId>
   <DeliveryDate>2019.01.23</DeliveryDate>
   <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <DeliveredQuantity>1</DeliveredQuantity>
  </Item>
 </LineInformation>
 <LineInformation>
  <Item>
   <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>
   <GTIN></GTIN>
   <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
   <PackingslipId>1079305</PackingslipId>
   <DeliveryDate>2019.01.23</DeliveryDate>
   <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <DeliveredQuantity>1</DeliveredQuantity>
  </Item>
 </LineInformation>
 <Totals />
</SALESINVOICE>
```

My XSLT:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 
  <!-- Delete PackingslipId and DeliveryDate on HeaderInformation, if PackingslipId on Line is different -->  
  <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[PackingslipId != LineInformation/Item/PackingslipId]/*[self::PackingslipId or self::DeliveryDate]" />
    
   <xsl:template match="LineInformation_TEMP">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
  </xsl:template>
    
  <!-- delete empty nodes
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) and normalize-space()='']"/>
 delete empty nodes -->
 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Correct XML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SALESINVOICE>
 <Interchange>
  <Recipient></Recipient>
  <Sender></Sender>
  <CreationDate></CreationDate>
  <Test></Test>
  <Interchange_Control_Number></Interchange_Control_Number>
 </Interchange>
 <HeaderInformation>
  <OrigInvoiceNumber>1</OrigInvoiceNumber>
  <InvoiceType>INVOIC</InvoiceType>
  <InvoiceDate>2019.01.23</InvoiceDate>
  <InvoiceNumber></InvoiceNumber>
  <PurchOrderReference>fddf</PurchOrderReference>
  <SalesOrderReference></SalesOrderReference>
  <CustomerOrderReference>fdgfdg</CustomerOrderReference>  
  <Currency></Currency>
  <WeightAndVolume />
  <DeliveryAddressInformation>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
  </DeliveryAddressInformation>
  <InvoiceAddressInformation>
   <GLN></GLN>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
   <VATNum></VATNum>
   <InternalNumber></InternalNumber>
  </InvoiceAddressInformation>
  <BuyerAddressInformation />
  <SupplierAddressInformation>
   <GLN></GLN>
   <Name></Name>
   <Street></Street>
   <ZipCode></ZipCode>
   <City></City>
   <Country></Country>
   <VATNum></VATNum>
   <Contact />
  </SupplierAddressInformation>
 </HeaderInformation>
 <LineInformation>
  <Item>
   <OrderLineNum>1</OrderLineNum>
   <GTIN></GTIN>
   <GTINDescription></GTINDescription>
   <PackingslipId>1079304</PackingslipId>
   <DeliveryDate>2019.01.23</DeliveryDate>
   <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <DeliveredQuantity>1</DeliveredQuantity>
  </Item>
 </LineInformation>
 <LineInformation>
  <Item>
   <OrderLineNum>2</OrderLineNum>
   <GTIN></GTIN>
   <GTINDescription>/GTINDescription>
   <PackingslipId>1079305</PackingslipId>
   <DeliveryDate>2019.01.23</DeliveryDate>
   <SupplierArticleNumber></SupplierArticleNumber>
   <Quantity>1</Quantity>
   <DeliveredQuantity>1</DeliveredQuantity>
  </Item>
 </LineInformation>
 <Totals />
</SALESINVOICE>
```

Best regards
Julian

Comment: Your current XSLT does produce the expected result. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ej9EGbQ. Although you could add `xsl:strip-space` if you wanted to remove the blank lines. Thanks!

Comment: hi, sorry i think i did some mistake in my xml. now i have edit with correct xml,
can you tell me whats wrong at my xslt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `LineInformation` is not a child of `HeaderInformation`, but a sibling, so use the `..` to get the parent element, and so then get the siblings, like so....

```
<xsl:template match="HeaderInformation[PackingslipId != ../LineInformation/Item/PackingslipId]
                     /*[self::PackingslipId or self::DeliveryDate]" />
```

EDIT: If you wanted to do it without the conditional expression in the match for whatever reason, try this XSLT instead...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

  <!-- Delete PackingslipId and DeliveryDate on HeaderInformation, if PackingslipId on Line is different -->  
  <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="PackingslipId != ../LineInformation/Item/PackingslipId">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="exclude" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PackingslipId|DeliveryDate" mode="exclude" />

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="exclude">
    <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="exclude" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: hmm at xslt-transformation online it works, but not in my tool which greats xml.

Comment: maybe we have to check the packingslipid on OrderLineNum 2 (if exists)??

Comment: this works: <xsl:template match="HeaderInformation/PackingslipId"/> but if i build some condition, it doesnt work

Comment: i dont know why, but also don´t work. do you know some if query?

Comment: If they XSLT you are using is different to what is shown in the question, then it is hard to say. Possibly because you have some template conflicts?.

Comment: i deleted my xslt and copy your query inside, but i dont know why it doesnt work. strange.. :(